# Change multiple properties of a DOM element with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function called `loadStyles()` here it is:

```
function loadStyles(url) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = url;
        link.media = 'all';
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(link);
}
```

I was wondering if there's another way of adding the values of certain properties except this one:
`link.rel` equals to `...`, `link.type` equals to `...`, etc.

I tried something like this:

```
function loadStyles(url) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link += {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: url,
        media: 'all'
    };
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(link);
}
```

But that doesn't work. I know it's probably stupid to even try it (because my  IDE says that this `{....}` expression is not assignable to type HTML element ^^').

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting multiple attributes for an element at once with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript)

Comment: I don't think you can natively "add" an object to a DOMElement, since it doesn't support it at all. The fastest solution you have is to either create a function and reference the object (and set every single property using a for loop) or to create your own class and pretend to accept an object of properties as a parameter (but you still will have to loop it to fill the DOMElement properties), which is what jQuery does for many prototypes (.css is an example). Also, you can also (eventually) extend the DOM object, but as far as I know this is not a good practice at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are nothing in JavaScript standard.

But you could use a function like that

```
function setAttributes(element, attributes) {
  for (var name in attributes) {
    element.setAttributes(name, attributes[name]);
  }
}

function loadStyles(url) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    setAttributes(link, {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: url,
        media: 'all'
    });
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(link);
}
```

I didn't test it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new object and merge it?

Means it should keep any properties an object currently has, unless they're being overwritten.

```
var newObj = {
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    type: 'text/css',
    href: url,
    media: 'all'
}

function merge_options(objOld,objNew){
    var objReturn = {};
    for (var attrname in objOld) { objReturn[attrname] = objOld[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in objNew) { objReturn[attrname] = objNew[attrname]; }
    return objReturn;
}

//Create New Object
var newLink = document.createElement('link');
merge_options(newLink, newObj);

//Update Current Object
var oldLink = document.querySelector('link');
merge_options(oldLink, newObj);
```