# Setting multiple attributes for an element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set multiple attributes to an element at one shot. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274886/4861207), and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript#comment37928331_12274886) to that answer. In the JSFiddle there, he doesn't use a string for the property name, as opposed to the answer which uses a string.

The problem with the JSFiddle in the comment, is that it doesn't have the ability to edit the text for the element. I tried adding that capability, but it didn't work.

I added the following at line 7:

```
else if (at[prop] === html) {
    this.innerHTML = set[idx];
}
```

But I got the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined

How can I add the functionality of changing the text to the commented JSFiddle?

#### Code

[**Answer JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ywrXX/1/)

[**Comment JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Spu/7/) (edited)

Comment: `html` is not defined in your code..I guess it should be `'html'` in condition..

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks! The error doesn't show up, but if you insert `console.log` in that if statement, you see it never gets called

Comment: Can you be more specific about ` doesn't have the ability to edit the text` ? Do you want to set different string rather 'hello' in the if-else loop? Because I don't get it why are you adding `else if (at[prop] === html) {
    this.innerHTML = set[idx];
}` in line 7? Did you change the variables in the given JSFiddle link because in that code, first of all `at[prop]` is not a variable. You may replace `attrs` with `at` but here `prop` is the index of `attrs[idx]`. So I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `'html'` in your comparison. Also pass `this` context in `recursiveSet` function to refer `this` to `div` element. `this` always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing. If there is no *owner*, it will refer to the `window`..

Try this:

```js
var manipulateAttributes = function(attr, element) {
  var recursiveSet = function(at, set) {
    for (var prop in at) {
      /* check if object and not a dom node or array */
      if (typeof at[prop] == 'object' && at[prop].dataset == null && at[prop][0] == null) {
        recursiveSet(at[prop], set [prop]);
      } else if (prop == 'html') {
        this.innerHTML = at[prop];
      } else {
        set [prop] = at[prop];
      }
    }
  }.bind(element);
  recursiveSet(attr, element);
}
var test = document.getElementById("test");

manipulateAttributes({
  html: 'hellop',
  style: {
    background: "lightGreen",
    color: "blue",
    width: "100px"
  },
  className: "testclass",
  onclick: function(e) {
    alert("the test div has been clicked and its width is: " + this.style.width);
  }
}, test);
```

```css
.testclass {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:#000;color:#fff;">Test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, how do I make it a function rather than extending the object?

Comment: I don't like extending a host object, i.e. this line: `Element.prototype.setAttributes`. How can I use it as a regular function?

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way of doing it with 1 function only? Meaning not having `recursiveSet`? I feel like it's repetitive.

Comment: Which do you suggest?

Comment: It is going to be lots of `if`s and `for...in` loop inside `for...in` loop...There is no other way..And it is not repetitive..

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (at[prop] === html) {
```

replace the above line of code as below to get into the loop

```
else if (at[prop] === 'hellop') {
```

Comment: Value of the key will be different in every cases..So you should be testing `key` of the object rather than value of the key...Makes sense ?