# Is there a way to set several attributes to one tag in one pass using raw string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

Is there any way to set DOM element attributes using raw string like this?

`data-attr1name="attr1val" data-attr2name="attr2val" data-attr3name="attr3val"`

Yes I can parse string and use `$(..).attr()` to set each value, but I'm looking for a way to avoid unnessessary double-conversion because of performance reasons (there could be a lot of data recieved from server and a lot of attributes per one tag, so setting all attributes for one tag by one pass could give effortable improvement at frontend). Anyway, if I already have a part of reday-to-use sanatized HTML-code - why not use it directly.

**UPD**: that is NOT duplicate of question about how to set multiple attributes at one call, because I'm looking a way to **avoid parsing attributes valueas at all**, so the following solution **doesnt answer** my question:

```
d.setAttributes({
'id':'my_div',
'class':'my_class',
'styles':{
    'backgroundColor':'blue',
    'color':'red'
},
'html':'lol'
});
```

because i still **have to** parse the source string such way

**UPD2** just to explain: this string sent by controller that generate it to be used in Smarty template like this: `<a href="#" class="someclasses"{$additional_tags}></a>`, but in this case I receive string not as a smarty variable but as a part of ajax answer.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to avoid. Can you just format the attribute value in such a way that it can be easily parsed to extract multiple different values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting multiple attributes for an element at once with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript)

Comment: @Pineda nope, not duplicate, I'm looking a way to avoid parsing at all

Comment: @kinakuta yes I can, but the key is _not_ to parse data at all, because I already have parsed and well-formed attributes as they will appear in HTML.

Comment: What is the format of your incoming attributes? JSON? Do you need to just store the data on the element, or do you actually need the elements to have those attributes?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I wrote format in the beginning of a question: `data-attr1name="attr1val" data-attr2name="attr2val" data-attr3name="attr3val"`. This data sent by controller that already generated string to be used in Smarty template like this `<a href="#" {$additional_tags}>`

Comment: You say you're trying to avoid double conversion? But there's no conversion involved when you assign the properties separately. The DOM is stored internally as objects, not as HTML strings. Conversion is only necessary when parsing the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar hmmm... do you mean that even if I'll find a way to avoid parsing - there will be an implicit 'string-to-internal' parsing, and I will not get any significant improvement?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. If you can operate on attributes directly, it's better.

Comment: @Barmar ok, got it... but I'm not sure that it's better to parse string by myself, at least because the internal parser should be optimized more... yes, improvement will be negligible, but in theory I guess it should be a little faster, no?

Comment: That's a good point. But if you want to use the internal parser, first you have to convert the DOM back to HTML, merge your string into it, and then parse it back into the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar agree, it looks like this way adds the unnessessary conversions instead of avoiding it :)  thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

This does answer the question, but is not necessarily a great idea.

It uses a replacement callback on `outerHTML`, and callbacks are nearly always more expensive than an alternative approach.

I can't imagine that the performance hit of setting attributes in sequence is significant unless you have a seriously crazy number of elements, but here goes nonetheless:

```
var
el = document.querySelector('p'),
attrs = 'style="color: blue" title="hello" data-etc="foo"';
el.outerHTML = el.outerHTML.replace(/<[^ >]+/i, function(tag) { return tag+' '+attrs; });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxL4tvzs)

Comment: ...but little test shown that it really more expensive then one-pass regexp parsing way :(

Comment: ...hmmm... but why?? callback is called once per match, in other words - once per tag as I wish... callback may be replaced with "match+concatenation"... internal parser shoul parse attributes faster then I... what is the reason of improvement hit??   yes, I know this discussion is out of the SE-format, so I'm sorry in advance :)... but really... why??

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know - that's really a separate question from your original one. One other performance hit is that my approach will necessarily cause a repaint, which will not necessarily be the case when adding attributes programmatically.

Comment: there is an idea born in original question comments: browser stores properties of loaded and parsed page not as a raw string but as a internal parsed structure... so if I try to add a string with properties directly to HTML it causes following sequence: internal-to-html-string conversion -> modifying HTML -> string-to-internal conversion by internal parser;  so we have two conversions here instead of only one conversion in case of parsing properties by myself;   That was really **not** obvious for me, but looks like that's true :)

Comment: ...and I agree that repaint could be very possible reason... maybe much more significant than "double-conversion" idea