# Why this doesn't bind using forEach, but does bind using a for in loop?

Tags: javascript

I was attempting to make a function that sets multiple attributes to an HTML element.  I used the code provided by a Stack Overflow user on this page

[Setting multiple attributes for an element at once with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript)

If I use a for in loop, the binding of this is successful, but if I use a forEach it is not?  Why is that?

**This Works**

```
Element.prototype.attributeSetter = function(attrs){
  for(var prop in attrs){
    if((prop == "style" || prop == "styles") && (typeof attrs[prop] === 'object')){
        for(var n in attrs[prop]){
           this.style[n] = attrs[prop][n];
        }
    }else if(prop == "html"){
        this.innerHTML = attrs[prop];
    }else{
        console.log("this: ", this);
        this.setAttribute(prop, attrs[prop]);
    }
  }
}
```

**This does not work**

```
Element.prototype.attributeSetter = function(attrs){
    Object.keys(attrs).forEach(function(prop){
      if((prop == "style" || prop == "styles") && (typeof attrs[prop] === 'object')){
         for(var n in attrs[prop]){
           this.style[n] = attrs[prop][n];
         }
      }else if(prop == "html"){
        this.innerHTML = attrs[prop];
      }else{
        //TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function
        console.log("this: ", this);
        this.setAttribute(prop, attrs[prop]);
      }
  });
}
```

However if I don't modify the Element Object and just make a regular function with the ForEach loop it works just fine.

Simple Implementation

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

myDiv.attributeSetter({
    class: "coolDiv",
  style: {
    color: "#0110ff",
    border: "2px solid lime"
  },
  "data-order": "one",
  "html": "Cool Div"
});
```

Comment: have you tried changing the second-last line of your 'This does not work' example to }.bind(this));

Comment: forEach is crap and slow, so.. yeah :).

Comment: @trevor Yeah, that works, but I was wondering why I have to do that.  Sorry if this is a poor question.

Comment: You have to do it because you are passing a callback function to the .forEach(). You don't know when your callback will execute, so you use .bind(this) to create a copy of your callback function that will execute at a future time in the context of myDiv. Although @Deep has a solution that works (called lexical capture of 'this'), it is not the best or most correct way of solving your issue. If you want to learn a lot about how these things work, I suggest reading the 'You Don't Know JS' series of books by Kyle Simpson, online and free: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Comment: @trevor Thanks, great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second snippet with foreach does not work because inside foreach **this** does not point to the div but to the window object and that is why you are getting error this.setAttribute is not a function

Change the implementation like below.

```js
Element.prototype.attributeSetter = function(attrs){
   var elem = this;
    Object.keys(attrs).forEach(function(prop){
      if((prop == "style" || prop == "styles") && (typeof attrs[prop] === 'object')){
         for(var n in attrs[prop]){
           elem.style[n] = attrs[prop][n];
         }
      }else if(prop == "html"){
        elem.innerHTML = attrs[prop];
      }else{
        //TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function
        elem.setAttribute(prop, attrs[prop]);
      }
  });
}

var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

myDiv.attributeSetter({
    class: "coolDiv",
  style: {
    color: "#0110ff",
    border: "2px solid lime"
  },
  "data-order": "one",
  "html": "Cool Div"
});
```

```html
 <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should brush up on .bind().  I mainly use JavaScript for design mainly.