# Avoiding repetition when dynamically creating HTML elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a button using javascript, and adding it to the page. This means I'll need an event, a class, and some text for the button, however, my current approach repeats the `aButton` five times, which seems excessive. I know that it's possible for simple attributes [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript), but this doesn't seem to work with `innerHTML` and `onclick`

```
let aButton = document.createElement('button');
aButton.classList.add("button-class");
aButton.innerHTML = "button text";
aButton.onclick = buttonFunction;
element.appendChild(aButton);
```

Is there a simpler approach using *vanilla JavaScript*? I don't mind repetition, but it seems there should be a way without repeating `aButton` five times.

Comment: A loop would be best suited here.

Comment: Create the elements inside a loop, but append them all at once outside of the loop.

Comment: If you used jQuery you could chain stuff: `$(element).append($("<button>").addClass("button-class").html("button text").click(buttonFunction));`

Comment: @OP: `innerHTML` isn't an attribute; an attribute is something you can set as part of the opening tag, like `href` or `class`. @Script47 As for using a loop... why? How?

Comment: @ChrisG I realized it's not an attribute, or it would've worked with the linked approach. I'd like to use javascript and avoid jquery if possible, as I know every javascript question has a trivial jquery solution.

Comment: The only way I can see is to write a custom function, but that doesn't really "solve" the "problem". JavaScript is clunky and long-winded for things like that, which is why jQuery was created.

Comment: @ChrisG *the DOM*

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry? Edit: "javascript" as in "using javascript to manipulate the DOM", obviously

Comment: @ChrisG I was mentioning that it's the DOM which is long winded.