# HTML DOM Select Object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I add multiple value in select option using javascript, my below script only show empty select option upon trigger.

```
var tr = document.createElement("TR");
     var td=document.createElement("TD");
        txt=document.createElement('SELECT');
        txt.style.width = '285px';
        txt.maxLength = 50;
        txt.setAttribute("type","text");
        txt.setAttribute("option","value","10001"),("text","Larry");
        txt.setAttribute("option","value","10002"),("text","Nancy");
        txt.setAttribute("class","form-control");
        txt.setAttribute("name","StoreCodeLine" + line);
        txt.setAttribute("id","StoreCodeLine" + line);
        td.setAttribute("align","center");
        td.appendChild(txt);
        tr.appendChild(td);
document.getElementById("tblGroup").appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: Can you give us the HTML or create a snippet so we can try please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting multiple attributes for an element at once with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript)

Comment: I don’t know where you got `txt.setAttribute("option", ..)` from, but it looks rather nonsense ... The options are independent HTML elements that reside inside the select, they aren’t attributes of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a loop for this,

```
var tr = document.createElement("TR");
 var td=document.createElement("TD");
    txt=document.createElement('SELECT');
    txt.style.width = '285px';
    txt.maxLength = 50;
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Larry";
    option.value = "10001";
    txt.add(option);
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Nancy";
    option.value = "10002";
    txt.add(option);
    txt.setAttribute("class","form-control");
    td.setAttribute("align","center");
    td.appendChild(txt);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    document.getElementById("tblGroup").appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: thanks you for understanding my question, its working on me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `option` is not a attribute, it's a **child element** of the `select`.

Also, the don't have an `text` attribute, you need to change the `innerHTML` of it:

```js
var line = 1;
var tr = document.createElement("TR");
     var td=document.createElement("TD");
        txt=document.createElement('SELECT');
        txt.style.width = '285px';
        txt.maxLength = 50;
        txt.setAttribute("type","text");
        txt.setAttribute("class","form-control");
        txt.setAttribute("name","StoreCodeLine" + line);
        txt.setAttribute("id","StoreCodeLine" + line);
        td.setAttribute("align","center");

        var opt1=document.createElement("option");
          opt1.setAttribute("value","10001");
          opt1.innerHTML = "Larry";
        var opt2=document.createElement("option");
          opt2.setAttribute("value","10002")
          opt2.innerHTML = "Nancy";
        txt.appendChild(opt1);
        txt.appendChild(opt2);
        td.appendChild(txt);
        tr.appendChild(td);
document.getElementById("tblGroup").appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table id="tblGroup"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks for unserstanding my question, I add txt.add(option); on your script thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like others already mentioned `option` is not its own attribute and it is a child element of `select`. You can directly append the options like below. First argument is `text` and the second one is `value`.

```
 txt.add(new Option("Larry","10001"));
 txt.add(new Option("Nancy","10002"));
```

```js
var tr = document.createElement("TR");
var td=document.createElement("TD");
    txt=document.createElement('SELECT');
    txt.style.width = '285px';
    txt.maxLength = 50;
    txt.setAttribute("type","text");        
    txt.add(new Option("Larry","10001"));
    txt.add(new Option("Nancy","10002"));
    txt.setAttribute("class","form-control");
    td.setAttribute("align","center");
    td.appendChild(txt);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    document.getElementById("tblGroup").appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table id="tblGroup">

</table>
```