# Passing an object into a function

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

In a DOM manipulation exercise, I was learning how to create HTML elements with pure Javascript. i.e. stuff like this:

```js
document.createElement()
setAttribute()
appendChild()
```

I have to create a function that allows a user to pass an object in as a parameter to set attributes onto an element. This object contains any number of keys (attribute) and values (attribute value). i.e. attribute could be "src" and value could be "image.jpg". Something to that effect. The user can pass as many attributes into this object as they want when calling the function.

The same function also creates the element that the attribute will be applied to but that isn't the part i'm stuck on.

How can I set up the function to accept an object and turn that objects contents in a setAttribute() method?

Side note, very new to code and JS, please bear with me :P

Comment: Iterate (loop) over the object keys / values and run `setAttribute(key, value)` for each one

Comment: Here's a post that will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript

There are many ways to achieve that, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let attributes = {
   "class": "some-class",
   "id": "unique-id",
  "style": "border: 1px solid tomato"
}

let title = document.createElement("h1");
title.textContent = "Title!";

Object.keys(attributes).forEach( key  => {
  title.setAttribute( key, attributes[key] );
  // key is elem
  // value is attributes[key]
});

document.body.appendChild( title );
```

Hope this helps.