# Add multiple times image dropping down the screen (video game js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, loops

So I am building a video game where some fireball drop down the screen. However, there is only one image crossing the screen at a time. I would like that the image is actually multiplied an number of times. To get an idea of what I am saying, here is an image: [image: This is my result now]

But what I would like to do is instead of only having one image (fireball) going down the screen, I would like to have a bunch of images dropping down the screen.

Here is the code for the fireball:

```
//Fireball script
function fFireball(offset) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - offset))
}
let fireball = {x: fFireball(fireballElement.offsetWidth), y: 0}
const fireLoop = function() {
    fireball.y += 2; fireballElement.style.top = fireball.y + 'px'
    if (fireball.y > window.innerHeight) {
        fireball.x = fFireball(fireballElement.offsetWidth)
        fireballElement.style.left = fireball.x + 'px'; fireball.y = 0
    }
}
fireballElement.style.left = fireball.x + 'px'
let fireInterval = setInterval(fireLoop, 1000 / 100)
```

And the image:

```
<img src="Photo/fireball.png" id="fireball">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Most games like this are build in canvas rather than CSS, I suspect you'll have better luck with that.

Comment: Would you consider using jquery or just stick with pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use document.createElement()

#### Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/hexzero/ukh1dpwn/

I wrote down several comments in the code below to help you understand it better. If you have any additional question don't hesitate to ask.

```js
const fireballArray = [];
// You can add any additional attributes you need for your fire balls here like ids and class names.
function generateFireBallWithAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for (var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
  return el;
}

function createFireBalls(amount){
for (let i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
  fireballArray.push(              // create an image element
    generateFireBallWithAttributes(document.createElement("img"), {
      src: "Photo/fireball.png",
      width: "32",
      height: "32",
    })
  );
}}

createFireBalls(10)

fireballArray.forEach((fireballElement) => {
  // Just add the id of the game body here, so that you could append your fire balls
  document.getElementById("game-body").appendChild(fireballElement);
  const fireball = { x: fFireball(fireballElement.offsetWidth), y: 0 };
  const fireLoop = function () {
    fireball.y += 2;
    fireballElement.style.top = fireball.y + "px";
    if (fireball.y > window.innerHeight) {
      fireball.x = fFireball(fireballElement.offsetWidth);
      fireballElement.style.left = fireball.x + "px";
      fireball.y = 0;
    }
  };
  fireballElement.style.left = fireball.x + "px";
  // I've randomised the interval
  // you may want to implement your own version to get more control
    let fireInterval = setInterval(fireLoop, 1000 / ((Math.random() * (125 - 75)) + 75));
});

function fFireball(offset) {  
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - offset));
}
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

I got inspired by this post [Setting multiple attributes for an element at once with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript), when adding extra attributes. If you like it please show them some love.

Comment: @Thomas fiddle works, for te snippet, you needed the #game-body to be there too ;) There was nothing wrong with the code . both answers here are giving you good tips .

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The snippet is only to display the code. Please use the demo above.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks for the edit. It was kind of you to do so, although I had to change it back. It was a mistake for me to leave it as a snippet in the first place.

Comment: @Thomas I'm glad to see you back from your suspension. I think when you create the Element it creates the element entity. As a HTML element. And you can save that to a variable of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new `<img>` element for each bullet

I created a snippet doing it the way you were doing it. However, it would be more efficient if you had a single loop that updates all of the images at once.

```js
const create = (x, y, vx, vy) => {
  const object = {
    x,
    y,
    vx,
    vy,
    el: document.createElement("img")
  }
  object.el.src = "http://placehold.it/50x50";
  object.el.style.left = `${object.x}px`;
  object.el.style.top = `${object.y}px`;
  document.body.appendChild(object.el);
  const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    object.x += object.vx;
    object.y += object.vy;
    object.el.style.left = `${object.x}px`;
    object.el.style.top = `${object.y}px`;
    if (object.y > window.innerHeight) {
      document.body.removeChild(object.el);
      clearInterval(intervalID)
    }
  }, 20);
}

setInterval(() => {
  const randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - 50));
  create(randX, -50, 0, 2);
}, 500);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}
```