# Set multiple attributes for an HTML element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to do this using jQuery at once.

```
var elem = document.createElement("img");
    
elem.setAttribute("src", "http://example.com/something.jpeg");
elem.setAttribute("height", "100%");
elem.setAttribute("width", "100%");
```

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript For jquery, take a look at: https://electrictoolbox.com/jquery-set-multiple-attributes/

Comment: This *is* explained on the jquery `.attr` page:  https://api.jquery.com/attr/  **Setting several attributes at once**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img').attr({'src':'http://example.com/something.jpeg', 'height':'100%', 'width':'100%'});
```

$('img') <= coresponding HTML element which you want to set the attributes

```
.attr(
    {
        'htmlAttributeName': 'attributeValue',
        'anotherHtmlAttributeName': 'attributeValue',
        ....
    }
)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: @LizeshShakya
OK, I edited my answer with code description