# How do I add multiple atrributes to an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

A string can contain attributes in the form like this:

```
let attr = ' min="0" step="5" max="100" ';
```

or

```
let attr = ' min="2019-12-25T19:30" ';
```

etc.

Is there a function (either JS or jQuery) to assign these attributes to a HTML element?

Similar to `setAttribute(name, value);` but for multiple attributes.

Comment: Why can't you just call the function multiple times? if those are different attributes calling it multiple times should work, if they are the same attributes, just append the new value to old value and update it then.

Comment: `let ele = document.getElementsByClassName("user-info")[0];`  `ele.min = "min";`  `console.log(ele.min);`  But your custom attrributes will not be visible in the tags, i guess.

Comment: Not unless you want to (re-)create the element's HTML code yourself in string form, and then let the browser parse it. It would probably make more sense to take your string value apart into name=value pairs first (via regular expression matching), and then loop over the result to use `setAttribute` with each one individually.

Comment: The element doesn't contain any attributes when it is created. Therefore there's no need to check if it exists or not.

Comment: Related: [Setting multiple attributes for an element at once with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript)

Comment: @Ivar that doesn't help as my values are not in an array.

Comment: Not with a string, but you can do `$('#inp').attr({min: "0", step: "5", max: "100"});`.

Comment: Then make it an array... -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any javascript method to do it, but you can convert your string to array and call `setAttribute` on the target element on every iterate of the array. like this:

```
let el = document.getElementById("targetId")  
let attrs = ' min="0" step="5" max="100" '.trim().replace(/\"/g,"").split(" ")
attrs.forEach(attr => {
  const [key,value] = attr.split('=');
  el.setAttribute(key,value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the answer at the following [Setting multiple attributes for an element at once with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript)

Quoting from there, you can use the following helper function

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
setAttributes(elem, {"src": "http://example.com/something.jpeg", "height": "100%", ...});
```